# Menu item doesn't open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have found a simple dropdown menu which works fine by me, but only the subitem links open.
When i click 'Home' nothing happens (it should open google page), when i click 'info2' google will open.

I think it has something to do with de .js file but i just dont see it.
Hope someone can help me out with a simple trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){
    if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
      // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
      $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
      $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");
      
      // open our new menu and add the open class
      $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
      $(this).addClass("open");
    }
    
    else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul, li, td {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol, ul { list-style: none; }

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }

/* nav menu styles */
#nav { 
  display: block; 
  width: 280px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

#nav li {font-size:19px; text-align:center;}

#nav > li > a { 
  display: block; 
  padding: 16px 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;
  background-color: #0069b3;
}
#nav > li > a:hover, #nav > li > a.open { 
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #384f76;
  background-color: #083562;
}

#nav li ul { display: none; background: #083562; }

#nav li ul li a { 
  display: block; 
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
  background: #014f86;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="w">

    
    <nav>
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Info</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">info2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">info3</a></li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>

    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if($(this).parent().has("ul")) { e.preventDefault();}` this is always true. Thus, the link won't be opened

Comment: @SimoneRossaini that's both incorrect and invalid HTML.

Comment: so use html like OP isn't good? because work in my system.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li    `<a>` into `<li>` is permitted.

Comment: `<li><a></a></li`> is fine. However `<a><li></li></a>` as your commented suggested is not.

Comment: Yes i mean that `<li><a></a></li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like .has() method can't be use in this way because not return boolean, but jQuery object. Change this:

```js
if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

To this and let me know if it helps you:

```js
if($(this).parent().has("ul").length === 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I know it's almost 2 months ago this one is solved, but can you/someone please take a look for me how to get this menu not closing anymore when clicking a submenu button / opening a page?

Comment: I think you can try to remove `removeClass("open")`. If not help please provide actual example of your code. Codesandbox or similar platform will be good place for this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. Is this something? https://codepen.io/Jorus/pen/LYbagEg         
Or cant you just get it by the Run Code Snippet? Hope you can still help me ;). Take your time.

Comment: Not sure what "not closing anymore when clicking a submenu button" mean. 
Could you please explain to me step by step what should happen after clicking the submenu?

Comment: The menu is now working, if you click on a submenu a new page opens and the menu is closing. So the submenu buttons are hidden. I would like them to stay open/visible when the page is open or refreshes, it's quite the same. Hope you understand me better now :P. Otherwise you could PM me if you like and i send you the page where its all about.